# Ajax dropdown list to search input to find weather using Yahoo Weather

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this code which will give a dropdown list of cities if selected will provide me with weather of that particular city. Data is pulled using Yahoo API.

This is the code,

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Find Weather in major cities around the worl</TITLE>
<META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="ajax, weather, api, fetch, yahoo">
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="yahoo, weather">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
<!--

$(document).ready(function(){

function get_weather()
{
var p = $("#code").val();

var u = ($('#u').attr('checked')) ? '&u=c' : '';
var to_load = 'get_weather.php?p='+ p + u;

$("#weather").html('<img style="margin-top: 104px;" src="ajax-loader.gif"   align="absmiddle">');

$("#weather").load(to_load);
}

$(window).load(get_weather); // Trigger "get_weather" when the window loads

// Trigger "get_weather" when the form objects are used
$("#code").change(get_weather);
$("#u").click(get_weather); 
});

//-->
</SCRIPT>

</HEAD>

<BODY>

<A target="_blank" HREF=""></A>

<center>

<div align="center">

<h2 align="center">Find World Weather</h2>

<form>
Get Weather for: <select id="code" name="code">
<option value="AFXX0001">Ghurian</option>
<option value="AFXX0002">Herat</option>
<option value="UKXX0687">Buckingham, United Kingdom</option>
<option value="ASXX0001">Adelaide, Australia</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" id="u" name="u" value="c">&nbsp;Change to degrees Celsius
</form>

<div id="weather"></div>
</div>
</center>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

But what I need is a search box in the place of dropdown list and when I enter a city I should get the weather information of that place. I am a beginner, so please treat me like that and uncomplicate all your answers. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might struggle with this, as you need to know the WOEID from yahoo for each location.  By the looks of things, there is no easy way to programatically get this.  In my opinion you would be better off using another weather service i.e.
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Birmingham,uk

It would seem they do some geo-coding of addresses themselves, but you could always use the google geocoding api in conjunction with this service.

Comment: I am planning to put all the WOEID myself, but can you tell me how to make a search box.

Comment: A search box is a simple: <input type='text' id='searchbox'/>  It depends on what that does, when you click submit.  What data will you be searching? An array? A database?  What have you already done?

Comment: I know that my friend, but what I need to know is how to convert this dropdown list input to search input. I mean the code for that.